# Ordering by COUNT() in SQL

Tags: sql, select, count, sql-order-by

Let's say I have a database table like this:

```
users
------
id
email
referrerID
```

How could I sort by the members with the most referrals?  I was trying something along the lines of:

```
SELECT id, email
FROM users
WHERE 1
ORDER BY COUNT(referrerID) DESC;
```

But this does not seem to work. I think that the default value 0 may also be affecting this somehow.

Comment: What is the PK of this table?

Comment: Primary Key. Does it have multiple rows per `id` or is `id` unique?

Comment: So you want to count up the most common values in the `referrerID` column to get the most prolific `referrerID`s? And you need the referrer email as well?

Comment: The email does not matter, just the id.  But I want to get the most common reffererID up top and descend down.  It would be awesome if the referrerID of 0 could be last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following clarification

```
SELECT referrerID,
       COUNT(id) as Num
FROM   users
GROUP  BY referrerID
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN referrerID = 0 THEN -1
            ELSE COUNT(id)
          END DESC;
```

Comment: The second one works, but is there a way to get the referrerID of 0 (zero) to be the last entry instead of above all of them?

Comment: @Flipper  `ORDER BY CASE WHEN referrerID = 0 THEN -1 ELSE COUNT(id)  END DESC`