# Sort search results by popularity using - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, search

I'm building a site that is mostly a collection of links to different pages and forms for a company's intranet. All the links are logged in a SQL database that has tables for specific links, the tags that connect to those links, and how often the link is used. Every time a link is used, it creates a row in the last table that contains

- an id for each row
- the link's id which is related to the table that contains the link's title and tags
- the actual link
- the date of the click.

I'm trying to figure out a way to sort the results based on the number of entries there are in the tracking database. I can search the database currently, but it just lists the results in the order they are in the database.

```
public ActionResult Index(string method = null)
    {
        var model = new SearchResults()
        {
            ContentLink = database.ContentLinks.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(method) && method != "").ToList(),
            ContentTag = database.ContentTags.Where(x => x.Tag.ToLower() == method).ToList()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

The results are passed into a model that contains lists for each respective table. I'm just trying to figure out a way that sorts the results based on which link has the most clicks logged in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a group by. I'm not clear on your exact entity/table structure, so you'll probably need to extrapolate an exact solution. Generally, it's going to be like:

```
var links = db.LinkClicks
    .GroupBy(m => m.Link)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count)
    .Select(m => m.Key);
```

`GroupBy` returns essentially a list of lists keyed by the property you're grouping by. Therefore, you can order by the count of each sub list to sort by the "popularity" of that particular link (what you're grouping by). Then, `Select` can be used to coallesce it into a simply list of the links, which will now be ordered by how many clicks each has.

Answer (score 0):

Return your Links based on [an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478710/ordering-by-count-in-sql). They will already be sorted.

```
SELECT links,
       COUNT(links) as LinkCount
FROM   youtable
GROUP  BY links
ORDER  BY COUNT(links) desc
```

You can drop the "COUNT(links) as LinkCount" line if you don't actually need the count.